# How to write python foundry's code workbook

Tags: palantir-foundry

How to write this sql code in Foundry's python code workbook

SELECT DISTINCT excl_rsn_id
FROM exclusion_current_1;

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can write that SQL statement in PySpark, using a dataset named `exclusion_current_1` in Code Workbooks:

1. Create a Code Workbook, and choose to import the `exclusion_current_1` dataset.
2. Click the blue `New transform` button and select `Python Code` to create a Python Transform.
3. In the Python Transform code viewer, enter this code:

   ```
   return exclusion_current_1.select("excl_rsn_id").distinct()
   ```
4. Click the blue `Preview` button to preview the resulting dataset.

Here is a screenshot of the final Code Workbook setup:

[image: final code workbook setup]